# knockout js valueupdate 'afterkeydown' with event change not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, event-handling

I'm using Knockout JS on a form that's used to calculate pricing for a product.

I have a function that is called on form submit and calculates pricing. For the text input fields, I'd like for the pricing function to be called as soon as user starts changing values. At the moment this only works if I click outside of the text input field, so not immediately on keypress/keyup, which is what I'd like to achieve.

I'm pretty sure it's something in my code that needs fixing.

**HTML for the input field:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Number of Pages</label>
    <input data-bind="value : pages, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown'], event: { change: onSubmit }" >
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
self.pages = ko.observable("10");

self.onSubmit = function () {

    self.response("<div class='priceLoading'>Loading</div>");

    var servURL = "http://prices.mysite.com/getpricing/"
        + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.selectedCategoryValue) + "/"
        + self.pages() + "/"
        + self.copies() 

    $.get(servURL, function (response) {
        self.response(response.PriceFormatted);
    })
}
```

The onSubmit function that is called on the event change grabs data xml data from a service and writes it on the form.

Any help with this greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried removing the brackets around the 'afterkeydown'? I am thinking its looking for the string, and you aren't giving that.

Comment: Removed the brackets but that did not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
<input data-bind="textInput : pages, event: { keyup: onSubmit }" >
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes a little more sense, if you want to submit on every change to your variable, to subscribe your onsubmit function to the variable rather than having a separate event.

```js
var self = {};

self.pages = ko.observable("10");
self.response = ko.observable();
self.copies = ko.observable("5");

self.pages.subscribe(function(newValue) {

  self.response("<div class='priceLoading'>Loading</div>");

  var servURL = "http://prices.mysite.com/getpricing/" + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.selectedCategoryValue) + "/" + self.pages() + "/" + self.copies()

  setTimeout(function() {
    self.response("Fetched for " + newValue);
  }, 500);
});

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Number of Pages</label>
  <input data-bind="value : pages, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'">
  <div data-bind="text:response"></div>
</div>
```